# Pandas: Clipping Time in DateTimeIndex depending on Date

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame with an DateTimeIndex: `yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS`

```
                       A  B  C
2015-08-08 16:00:00    1  2  3
2015-08-08 16:00:08    4  5  6
...
```

I would like to extract rows that are in a certain time range `HH:MM:SS`. However, this time range differs for each date `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Is it possible to use some sort of dictionary that maps  dates to time ranges and the clip the DateTimeIndex accordingly?

Comment: I think that all you need is str.split ...

Comment: Does each individual date have a different time range, or is there a pattern to the ranges?  (e.g. on Saturdays, the range is 8am-10am, etc.)

Comment: There is no clear pattern. It is calculated based on statistical data (for each day)

Comment: So what do you expect the output be like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter by dict of lists for starts and end times with list comprehension for `list` of filtered `DataFrames` by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html).

Last [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) them to one:

```
print (df)
                     A  B  C
2015-08-08 16:00:00  1  2  3
2015-08-09 13:00:08  4  5  6
2015-08-09 13:00:10  4  5  7

d = {'2015-08-08':['16:00:00', '16:00:10'],'2015-08-09':['13:00:08', '13:00:20']}

df1 = pd.concat([df.loc[k + ' ' + v[0] : k + ' ' + v[1]] for k, v in d.items()])
print (df1)
                     A  B  C
2015-08-09 13:00:08  4  5  6
2015-08-09 13:00:10  4  5  7
2015-08-08 16:00:00  1  2  3
```

Another solution with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = pd.concat([df[(df.index >= k + ' ' + v[0]) & 
                    (df.index <= k + ' ' + v[1])] for k, v in d.items()])
print (df1)
                     A  B  C
2015-08-09 13:00:08  4  5  6
2015-08-09 13:00:10  4  5  7
2015-08-08 16:00:00  1  2  3
```